# ipython - pandasql.sqldf doesn't return an error

Tags: pandas, ipython

After importing

```
import pandas
import pandasql
```

and running:

```
q = """
select  min(cast (maxtempi as integer))
from weather_data
where  min(cast (maxtempi as integer)) >55
"""

print pandasql.sqldf(q.lower(), locals())
```

## None

is returned and no result sets or error.  Obviously the error is in the where clause.
How do I print an error from pandasql.sqldf?

Comment: Do you have the `weather_data` or something similar to reproduce the issue?

Comment: might not be the where clause. are you able to return anything from that dataframe? I'm having a similar problem (ipython 3.1.0, pandas 0.16, pandasql 0.6.2). in my case, it doesn't work in ipython notebook, otherwise works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Normal, it should be fine and no error occurs. 
please also notice and check followings;
(1)is weather_data an instance of DataFrame?
(2)is pandasql installed? If you use PyCharm, please also restart your PyCharm to let new installed pandasql package works

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).